# Strip multiline markdown comment in bash

Tags: bash, markdown

How do I strip multi-line markdown comments, such as the one below, in bash?

```
some text

<!-- QUESTION:
How do I remove everything
in-between these tags? 
 -->

some<!-- Including embedded single-line comments such as this --> text
```

I've tried `sed -e 's/<!--((.*?)\n?)+-->//g' $1`, which works only with single line, and `cat $1 | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e 's/<!--.*-->//g' | tr '\r' '\n'`, which removes everything after the first multiline comment.

`<!--((.*?)\n?)+-->` captures the required area in my text-editor, but 
`sed -e 's/<!--((.*?)\n?)+-->//g' $1` doesn't work as expected.

Other examples I can find that works with C++ comments are too complicated to decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a perl one-liner.

**Perl Switches**:

```
-0 sets the input record separator to the null character \0
-p prints the result of perl code
-e executes the following code
```

**Inside the regular expression**:

```
g flag means global (perform the replacement as many times as possible)
s flag means treat the input as a multi-line string

Match the characters `<!--` followed by anything up to the characters `-->`
including anything after that till the newline.  Replace that with nothing.
```

**In Action**:

```
perl -0pe 's|<!--.+?-->.*?\n||gs;' input
```

**Output**:

```
some text


some text
```

Comment: What I needed was actually to exclude everything outside the comment, so that single line comments in between the text can also be stripped. 
So I modified your code into this: `perl -0pe 's|<!--(.*?)\n?-->||gs;'  $1` and it worked!

Comment: This doesn't handle html comments in code blocks ```

Comment: How about providing an example?  Or start another question?